# Rewriting method declaration

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm iterating over the methods in a type and have to rewrite those that aren't static. I'd have to insert a parameter either as the first or the last parameter but can't figure out how to create the `ParameterSyntax` object

This is what I have so far

```
var methods = from m in r.Members.OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
              where !m.Modifiers.Contains(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.StaticKeyword))
              select new {
                   orgMethodDecl = m, 
                   rewrittenDecl = RewriteMethodDeclaration(m,name)};

                   var rewrittenType = r;
                   foreach(var m in methods){
                        rewrittenType = rewrittenType.ReplaceNode(m.orgMethodDecl, m.rewrittenDecl);
                   }
```

and the `RewriteMethodDeclaration` is where I have the issue

```
    MethodDeclarationSyntax RewriteMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax method, string name)
    {
        var p = Syntax.Parameter(); //type dynamic, name: name
        var parameters = method.ParameterList.AddParameters(p);
        return method.WithParameterList(parameters);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
static MethodDeclarationSyntax 
    RewriteMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax method, string name)
{
    var type = Syntax.ParseTypeName("dynamic");
    var identifier = Syntax.Identifier(String.Format(" {0}", name));
    var p = Syntax.Parameter(
        new SyntaxList<AttributeListSyntax>(),
        new SyntaxTokenList(),
        type,
        identifier,
        null);
    var parameters = method.ParameterList.AddParameters(p);
    return method.WithParameterList(parameters);
}
```